# Cloudfront static sites with versioning

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, static-site

I like the idea of hosting a static site in S3 + Cloudfront.

Best practice seems to be to version files in S3. For example, for site version `2324`, I'd put stuff in

```
s3://my-site-assets/2324/images/logo.jpg
```

The thing I'm having trouble with is how to version the actual pages. If a "hello" page is at

```
s3://my-site-assets/2324/hello.html
```

I would want visitors to `https://my-site.com/hello.html` to get the correct version.

Is this possible with a 100% static site? Right now, I'm doing something similar by versioning assets, but my pages are all served via EC2/Varnish/ELB. It seems quite heavyweight just for rewriting `hello.html` -> `2324/hello.html`.

Comment: @squidpickels have you solved this problem?

Comment: @MananShah no luck, but I haven't been working on that problem recently.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible today with [Lambda@Edge](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/edge) You have to do server side redirection to load latest versioned site. Since you're versioning your site, somewhere you must be maintaining the version. Use that number in your lambda@edge logic.

Request (https://my-site.com/hello.html) -> L@E (redirect here) -> CF -> S3 (and all the way back)

L@E logic: `replace(base_url, base_url+/+${latest_version})`

Reference doc on routing via Lambda@Edge: https://making.close.com/posts/redirects-using-cloudfront-lambda-edge